# scipy.optimize.newton gives TypeError: 'float' object is not callable

Tags: python, scipy, typeerror, newtons-method

Im new to python and I was writing this simply code for finding the roots of the function:

```
from scipy import optimize

x = eval(raw_input())                           #Initial guess
f = eval(raw_input())                           # function to be evaluated
F = eval(raw_input())                          #derivative of function f

round(optimize.newton(f, x, F, tol = 1.0e-9), 4)
```

But the interpreter returns:
TypeError: 'float' object is not callable

I'm really not sure what im missing out from this code. Can someone help me out..thank you in advance

Comment: you are evaluating `raw_input`, likely becoming a float, for `f`. `newton` is expecting a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`optimize.newton` expects a reference to a callable object (for example a function). That does not mean that you give a function as a string like `'x*x'` but you have to define one first, like:

```
def my_func (x):
    return x*x
```

Then you can plug `my_func` into `optimize.newton` (besides the other required parameters).

Answer (score 0):

This will depend on what you are inputting for `f`. If you enter something like

```
lambda x: x ** 2
```

then it will be interpreted as a function, for example

```
In [83]: f = eval('lambda x: x ** 2')

In [84]: f(5)
Out[84]: 25
```